# A lot problem on vendor after i create project laravel

Tags: php, laravel, syntax, backend

So, i want to study laravel 9, but after i create project laravel , there is a lot of problem inside file vendor. There r 1k problems. Syntax error: unexpected token function.... etc. I tried to created a new project , but there is still a lot of problems inside vendor folder. [image: hierachy]

How to resolve this problems. I dont know what should i do

Comment: Ok, check your PHP version on your system and update your original question. The 'problems' cone from your VSCode that is analyzing the vendor folder. Try to make your IDE ignore the vendor folder

Comment: my php version 8.1.10 (cli). All of problem is "Syntax error : unexpected token 'function' " . Can u tell me how to make IDE ignore the vendor folder pls?

Comment: What are the stack trace? 
how did you installed laravel?

Comment: i use composer to instal laravel.

Comment: Create a `.gitignore` file at the root of your project if it doesn't exist already. Then, paste the contents of https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Laravel.gitignore into that file. Notice the `.` (dot) in front of the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before. What I did was I uninstalled all the PHP extensions on my VS Code. All the alerts were gone in an instant. I just installed them again one after another to see what was causing the problem.

Comment: Thx , i already uninstall all php extension on my vs code and all alert were gone.